# Cannot pull code from heroku : the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: heroku, public-key

I'm new to heroku. I uploaded my rsa key and then tried pulling the starter code for a Facebook app that I'm trying to make but when I use the git clone command, I keep on getting the message fatal:

```
The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

What could be the possible reasons for this message to turn up. I have verified that my rsa key exists on the heroku server by using the command heroku keys and it did return the same key which I had created.

Comment: Does running `heroku login` with your credentials change something ?

Comment: Are you cloning the code from heroku? Or from github?

Comment: @pjam: No heroku login with my credentials doesn't change anything.

Comment: @mc6688: I'm cloning the code from heroku

Comment: Where's the repo located? Can you post the link?

Answer (score 0):

try this

heroku keys:add

i added the keys and then did the whole process of git phush again and it worked fine for me 
hope this helps

Details at "Managing Your SSH Keys": https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys